# Magento Cart Discount Rule

Tags: discount

Hi i need a discount rule that looks at all the products in the cart > if the total of products in the cart from category A ≥$2500 > 15% discount is applied to the amount over 2500. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the cart price rule with the condition of product selection combination for category and order total.

Below is the Sample I have shared with the sample configuration
[image]